# Spring Data Neo4j 4 and Pageable @QueryResult

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j-4

I'm trying to introduce `Pageable` support for my custom Cyper query over SDN 4 Repository method:

```
@Query(value = "MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) WHERE id(parentD) = {decisionId} OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(vg:VoteGroup)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c:Criterion) WHERE id(c) IN {criteriaIds} WITH childD, ru, u, vg.avgVotesWeight as weight RETURN childD AS decision, ru, u, sum(weight) as weight ORDER BY weight DESC", countQuery="MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision) WHERE id(parentD) = {decisionId} RETURN count(childD)")
Page<WeightedDecision> getChildDecisionsSortedBySumOfCriteriaAvgVotesWeight(@Param("decisionId") Long decisionId, @Param("criteriaIds") Set<Long> criteriaIds, Pageable pageable);
```

`WeightedDecision` is a @QueryResult:

```
@QueryResult
public class WeightedDecision {

    private Decision decision;

    private double weight;

    public Decision getDecision() {
        return decision;
    }

    public void setDecision(Decision decision) {
        this.decision = decision;
    }

    public double getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(double weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

}
```

Right now this logic fails with a `ClassCastException` exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.domain.model.decision.result.WeightedDecision cannot be cast to org.springframework.data.domain.Page
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it ?

Comment: Reproduced this issue as a bug in OGM (or SDN, rather).  Working on a fix. Will keep you posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version 2.0.4 of SDN did not support paging for `@QueryResult`s. Version 2.0.5 *will* support this, and the feature is available for UAT in the snapshot build repository.

Comment: I'd like to confirm that it is working now with OGM 2.0.5-SNAPSHOT and SDN 4.2.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT. Thanks !!!