# Spring does not find the symbol @QueryResult

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I am working on linking a Neo4J database to a spring-data application. I would like to add an annotation @QueryResult to a class but it says java: cannot find symbol. And, I cannot import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation

In my pom.xml I have :

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Thank you for your help and answers.

Comment: I hope this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38739787/7199780 may be helpful.

Comment: The link refers to a very outdated answer. Spring Data Neo4j is at version 6 now, which is completely different from the previous major versions.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are using (the latest release of) Spring Boot.
In that case, you are using Spring Data Neo4j 6 and `@QueryResult` is not defined anymore. You can achieve projections as described [there](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/6.0.0/reference/html/#projections).

Comment: Should at least provide a high-level overview of what the link was supposed to lead to, as the link is dead. Wouldn't have to be fancy, just enough for a dev to start researching on his own should the link die.

Comment: Link fixed, thanks.